# who decides the page table and page size? OS or MMU?

Tags: operating-system, mmu

with physical Memory capacity  changes the page table size is changes, with number of processes changes page table size changes. who actually decides it? OS or MMU?
if OS, any differences are there between LINUX and Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page table sizes are fixed for CPU operating mode. OS can't modify it. Some processors allow for multiple page sizes and the OS can decide which one to use.

Comment: it is the case of normal environment. in cases of virtualization the para drivers installed inside the os can provisions the physical memnory change at run time and during that i observed page table size changes dynamically.